# jQuery if statement depending on width in px

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, width

I'm quite new to jQuery, could someone please tell me if I have expressed the above 'if' statement correctly? I basically want something to run if the width of my variable equals 900px. My variable is `var $brewapp = $('#brewapp');`

Thanks.

```
if (($brewapp).width == '900px')
{
//what i want it to do
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is a function, that returns a number. So your test should look like this:

```
if ($brewapp.width() === 900)
```

I suggest the [Mozilla Javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) if you want to deepen your JS knowledge.

Comment: The only answer on the page that doesn't use type coercion.
You sir are getting voted up!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add only two characters:

```
if ($brewapp.width() == 900)
{
//what i want it to do
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, got it working in the end. Still having problems with the script but go that part of it working.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code should be:

```
if ($brewapp.width() == 900)
{
//what i want it to do
}
```

First width is a function, so use () and it returns an integer, so no need to append 'px'.

This is the jQuery way. Using the jQuery width() gives better results than using el.style.width (or what you intended to use).