# how to control jquery according to media screen?

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

I want to use this jquery only on resposive template and want to disable it in desktop and laptop screen width

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.searchkey').click(function(){
    $('.search').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10){
          $('.search').hide('fast'); 
    }
});
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                   $('.bottom_menu').hide();
                }else {
                    $(this).scrollTop() > 10
                    $('.bottom_menu').show('fast');
                }
            });
        });
```

I want this code only work in windows width < 1000  and i have tried that code as well but it didn't work

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($(this).width() < 1000) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.searchkey').click(function(){
    $('.search').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10){
          $('.search').hide('fast'); 
    }
});
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
                   $('.bottom_menu').hide();
                }else {
                    $(this).scrollTop() > 10
                    $('.bottom_menu').show('fast');
                }
            });
        });
   }
});
```

Comment: check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136193/jquery-if-statement-depending-on-width-in-px and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/jquery-do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px

Comment: @MaryMelody it's good i knew about that but my question is that how i can put that code in this code $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 960) { how i can attach that code with this code i have tried it many of time but it's couldn't work ... i tried it like as check again my question i update it again

Comment: Try switching $(document).ready with $(window).resize.

Comment: @Tim i try it like as http://jsfiddle.net/Lpu2sxrh/ but it's not work maybe here is some error if you will check it and fix it for me ... maybe it will be work

Comment: You have a problem with this line: `$(this).scrollTop() > 10`.

Comment: @flowstoneknight i can remove this line then what i need to have to do ...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put an `if` statement inside each function that you want to restrict. So when the function is called, it first checks to see if the window is the appropriate size. Something like this:

```
function functionName() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        //function code here
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm2751rc/).